# how to implement a section block in eLearning module - odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

i was tryin to add a section block which allows me to block all the possible sections (except for the first) and then if all the slides in the section are complete, makes the next one available
I tried with the templates but it don't seem the way to approach this problem cause I cannot find any way to check the previous slides, I was trying to figure it out with javascript maybe but I'm not that good with JS
that's my actual progress:

```
<odoo>
<data>
        <template id="section_lock" inherit_id='website_slides.course_slides_list_slide'>
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='text-truncate mr-auto']" position="replace">
                <div class="text-truncate mr-auto">
                    <a t-if="slide.is_preview or slide.previous_category_complete is False or channel.can_publish"
                       class="o_wslides_js_slides_list_slide_link" t-attf-href="/slides/slide/#{slug(slide)}">
                        <span t-field="slide.name"/>
                    </a>
                    <span t-else="">
                        <span t-esc="slide.name"/>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
```

and then the model with the flag needed for the check

```
class Slide(models.Model):
_inherit = 'slide.slide'

previous_category_complete = fields.Boolean(default=True)
```

how do u suggest to do it? I think i'm way off th road with this

Comment: Le'ts investigate the controller file main.py (located in directory controllers of the elearning module)

Comment: which field (m2o) or model makes the relation between each course (model: slide.slide) and its sections ?

Comment: @sylvain what should i look inside the controller?

Comment: no one btw, the section is a slide.slide entity, is just a slide with the "is_category" flag True

Comment: uh i just saw these were before the answer, my bad

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between an e-Course and its section is based on the same model (slide.slide) using these relational fields :

```py
    category_id = fields.Many2one('slide.slide', string="Section", compute="_compute_category_id", store=True)
    slide_ids = fields.One2many('slide.slide', "category_id", string="Slides")

    @api.depends('channel_id.slide_ids.is_category', 'channel_id.slide_ids.sequence')
    def _compute_category_id(self):
       
        self.category_id = False  # initialize whatever the state

        channel_slides = {}
        for slide in self:
            if slide.channel_id.id not in channel_slides:
                channel_slides[slide.channel_id.id] = slide.channel_id.slide_ids

        for cid, slides in channel_slides.items():
            current_category = self.env['slide.slide']
            slide_list = list(slides)
            slide_list.sort(key=lambda s: (s.sequence, not s.is_category))
            for slide in slide_list:
                if slide.is_category:
                    current_category = slide
                elif slide.category_id != current_category:
                    slide.category_id = current_category.id
```

To know wether a specific student has attended an e-course, there is an existing field in the model 'slide.slide.partner':

```py
class SlidePartnerRelation(models.Model):
    _name = 'slide.slide.partner'
    
    slide_id = fields.Many2one('slide.slide', ondelete="cascade", index=True, required=True)
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', index=True, required=True, ondelete='cascade')
    completed = fields.Boolean('Completed')
```

So you can check wether all the previous Slide Sections are completed for the current partner_id,  inheriting the class WebsiteSlides located in website_slides/controllers/main.py  > def channel(...)... :

```py
from odoo.addons.website_slides.controllers.main import WebsiteSlides

class WebsiteSlidesCustom(WebsiteSlides):

    @http.route()
    def channel(self, channel, category=None, tag=None, page=1, slide_type=None, uncategorized=False, sorting=None, search=None, **kw):

        res_super = super(WebsiteSlidesCustom, self).channel(channel,        category=None, tag=None, page=1, slide_type=None, uncategorized=False, sorting=None, search=None, **kw)

        values = res_super.qcontext

        sections_completion = request.env['slide.slide.partner'].sudo().search([
            ('channel_id', '=', current_channel_id),
            ('is_category','=', True),
            ('partner_id', '=', request.env.user.partner_id.id)
        ])

        dic_sections_completion={}
        for sec in sections_completion.sorted('sequence'):
          dic_sections_completion[sec.id] = sec.completed

        values['sections_completion'] = dic_sections_completion

        return request.render('website_slides.course_main', values)
```

in your module directory views, create a new xml file : course_main_custom.xml

```xml
         <template id="course_main_custom" inherit_id="website_slides.course_main" name="Course Main" >
            <xpath expr="//t[@t-set='category']" position="after">
             ...
            </xpath>
          </template>
```

Comment: but there's no current_partner/slide field in slide.slide
if i paste the last block it will still work fine even without those fields in the slide.slide? (idk if they're like some odoo definitions or else, i'm still a beginner with it)

Comment: current_partner= request.env.user.partner_id.id

Comment: the issue is i cannot modify the core module, i'm working on a custom module for this implementation
btw, even if i copy-paste the last block inside the core module, how could i manage the xml to add this new block?
btw many thanks for all this help <3

Comment: how to inherit model using your custom module: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46yecsKX2tw

Comment: how to inherit view using your custom module:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iY3ea-wvjw

Comment: thank, i'm trying to inherit the controller and add the part u gave me, i 'll let u know if it works fine

Comment: hey, do u have any social where can i write to u? StackOverflow suggest me to use the chat but i don't have enough reputation so i can't, if for u isn't a problem we could end up that rapidly with small chat

Comment: btw it ain't worked, i pasted it inside the inherited controller and updated the module but nothing happened, idk if i have to do anything else other pastin it in the controller

Comment: yes, i have just given you guide lines, not the whole work... without advanced understanding of odoo development, it seems to be too complicated

Comment: uh ok, thx btw, i will try to figure it out i guess, i'm stuck on this task since may....